# Form not working properly?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a website with offers with php. I have a function that I use in a for loop with and the results from the database are passed in the function. The code is like this:

```
<?php 
function table_values($row0,$row1,$row2,$row3,$row4,$row5){

    $table_element = "<div id=\"$row0\" class='tab'>
                                    <div class='tab-header'>";
        switch ($row1) {
            case "Tiscali":
                $img = "<img src='images/tiscali.png' alt='Tiscali' />";
                break;
            case "Infostrada":
                $img = "<img src='images/infostrada.png' alt='Infostrada' />";
                break;
            case "Fastweb":
                $img = "<img src='images/fastweb.png' alt='Fastweb' />";
                break;
            case "TIM":
                $img = "<img src='images/telecom-italia.png' alt='TIM' />";
                break;
        }
        $table_element = "".
            $table_element . " $img <span>$row2</span></div>
                                <div class='block'>
                                    <div class='first-set-block'>
                                        <span class='s2'>Download</span><br /><span class='s3'>$row3 Mbps</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class='first-set-block'>
                                        <span class='s4'>ATTIVAZIONE</span><br /><span class='s5'>GRATUITA</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class='block'>
                                    <div class='block-header'>
                                        Costo standard
                                    </div>
                                    <div class='block-describe-standard'>
                                        <span class='s6'>&#8364; $row4</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class='block'>
                                    <div class='block-header'>
                                        Promozione
                                    </div>
                                    <div class='block-describe-promozione'>
                                        <span class='s7'>&#8364; $row5</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class='block'>
                                    <div class='block-header-last'>
                                        Costo 1 anno
                                    </div>
                                    <div class='block-describe-costo'>
                                        <span class='desc1'>&#8364; 21</span>
                                        <span class='desc2'>.32<br />&#8364;/mese</span>
                                        <button class='ordina-offerta'>Ordina</button>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                               </div>
                               <div class='black'>
                                    </div>
                               <div class='popup' id='pop".$row0."'>
                               <form method='post' action='off.php'>
                                    <span class='close'>&times;</span>


                                    <table width='100%' style='text-align: center;'>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Nome: </td><td><input type='text' name='nome' /></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Cognome: </td><td><input type='text' name='cognome' /></td>
                                        </tr>
                                         <tr>
                                            <td>id: </td><td><input type='text' name='id' value=\"$row0\" /></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td colspan='2'><input type='submit' value='Carica' class='carica' /></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table> 
                                </form>
                                </div>";

                return $table_element;
            }
?>
```

but for one reason i want that the div black and div popup to be child of the div class tab but when i change the code from that above to this the submit button doesn't work.

```
<?php 
function table_values($row0,$row1,$row2,$row3,$row4,$row5){

    $table_element = "<div id=\"$row0\" class='tab'>
                                    <div class='tab-header'>";
        switch ($row1) {
            case "Tiscali":
                $img = "<img src='images/tiscali.png' alt='Tiscali' />";
                break;
            case "Infostrada":
                $img = "<img src='images/infostrada.png' alt='Infostrada' />";
                break;
            case "Fastweb":
                $img = "<img src='images/fastweb.png' alt='Fastweb' />";
                break;
            case "TIM":
                $img = "<img src='images/telecom-italia.png' alt='TIM' />";
                break;
        }
            $table_element = "".
                $table_element . " $img <span>$row2</span></div>
                            <div class='block'>
                                <div class='first-set-block'>
                                    <span class='s2'>Download</span><br /><span class='s3'>$row3 Mbps</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class='first-set-block'>
                                    <span class='s4'>ATTIVAZIONE</span><br /><span class='s5'>GRATUITA</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class='block'>
                                <div class='block-header'>
                                    Costo standard
                                </div>
                                <div class='block-describe-standard'>
                                    <span class='s6'>&#8364; $row4</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class='block'>
                                <div class='block-header'>
                                    Promozione
                                </div>
                                <div class='block-describe-promozione'>
                                    <span class='s7'>&#8364; $row5</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class='block'>
                                <div class='block-header-last'>
                                    Costo 1 anno
                                </div>
                                <div class='block-describe-costo'>
                                    <span class='desc1'>&#8364; 21</span>
                                    <span class='desc2'>.32<br />&#8364;/mese</span>
                                    <button class='ordina-offerta'>Ordina</button>
                                </div>

                            </div>

                           <div class='black'>
                                </div>
                           <div class='popup' id='pop".$row0."'>
                           <form method='post' action='off.php'>
                                <span class='close'>&times;</span>


                                <table width='100%' style='text-align: center;'>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Nome: </td><td><input type='text' name='nome' /></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Cognome: </td><td><input type='text' name='cognome' /></td>
                                    </tr>
                                     <tr>
                                        <td>id: </td><td><input type='text' name='id' value=\"$row0\" /></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan='2'><input type='submit' value='Carica' class='carica' /></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table> 
                            </form>
                            </div></div>";

                return $table_element;
            }
?>
```

Does anybody know why? I need to make them children of tab class for jquery reasons to use the `parent()` function.. Thanks in advance, hope that i was clear.

Comment: "hope that i was clear" - you were not clear. How can we know, why do you need to use "tab" class for div?

Comment: Ok i'm a little bit new and the code isn't perfectly clear, i wanted to make them children of tab class for this jquery code

Comment: I don't see any JQuery code in your question. Please provide a minimal working example as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: the jquery code is in the main page, and is like this    $(document).ready(function(){       $('.tab').click(function(){                                                                           var  id=$(this).attr('id');                                                                                         $('#black' + id).fadeIn();                                                    $('#pop' + id).fadeIn();                                                                    return false;            }); //The first part of Jquery code

Comment: Look at the answer below, I added the Jquery code too.

Answer (score 0):

Forms created from scratch dynamically (using JS) will not be handled correctly since it was inserted to the page after it was loaded as it's shown above the code. instead you can create the form using the HTML code and after that you can change elements using JS according to data coming from server(PHP code).
Hope this helps.

Comment: a little bit but still in fact i think is better to show all the project code and the idea way i have choose this kind of way, as i said this is a web with offers and all the offers and price are stored in db, and when i retrieve the values i build dynamically the table with some div tags and inside i have a hidden dialog window with black screen that appears as a popup when the client click the offer, the popup has the name field surname and the id which in fact i have thought about it to make it hidden and throw that id i know that this client with this name and surname want this offer.

Comment: I am right now working on similar project as you do, and I can tell you that %100 dynamically generated content is a huge mistake , what you can do is to draw the main design with your HTML code such as `<input id="" type="">` and the data coming from the DB would be better if it's JSON and according to the coming parameters you can change the element properties using JQuery.

Comment: Yes now i see your point, no in fact is mysql, i don't know JSON never tried to learn it, to be honest since i'm a bit new in web development i thought that is better to stick with one or two things and try to learn them as much as possible and then in future will give a shoot to learn JSON or Node.js or other kind of ways and technics in web developing

Comment: If you are doing this web application for learning it's okay to go like this but otherwise I highly suggest you go as I told you , it will take you some time and effort to learn but greatly better results.

Comment: Hey buddy can you take a look at the answer below that I added, maybe you will get a clear idea why I wanted to make the popup class and black class children of tab class..

Answer (score 0):

This is the Jquery part wich is include in the main page..

```
    
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.tab').click(function(){
            var id=$(this).attr('id');
                $('#black' + id).fadeIn();
                $('#pop' + id).fadeIn();
                return false;
            });
            $('.close').click(function(){
            var id=$(this).parent().parent().parent().attr('id');
                $('#black' + id).fadeOut();
                $('#pop' + id).fadeOut();
                $( '.grazie-popup' ).fadeOut();
                return false;
            });
            $('.black').click(function(){
            var id=$(this).parent().attr('id');
                $('#black' + id).fadeOut();
                $('#pop' + id).fadeOut();
                $( '.grazie-popup' ).fadeOut();
                return false;
            });
            if ( $( '.grazie-popup' ).length ) {
                $('#black').delay( 400 ).fadeIn();
                $( '.grazie-popup' ).delay( 600 ).fadeIn();
            }
        });
```

And the problem is as I explained to before when i want to make the < div class="black"> and < div class="popup"> children of < div class="tab"> the submit button doesn't work.